# Conversion from T to unsigned int, possible loss of data

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to build a dynamic array template class, so far everything has been going good until i tried to use a new object instance of type double, it throws an error as such:

Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from 'T' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

and

Error   C2108   subscript is not of integral type

my problem hangs in the Vector(T aSize) function

ive had a look around and i can understand these errors but trying to apply the fix doesn't seem to be work, any help would be awesome.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    Vector<int> test = Vector<int>(5);
    Vector<double> test2 = Vector<double>(10);

    test.insert(1, 8);
    test.insert(3, 22);
    test.getPosition(0);
    test.getSize();
    test.print();
    test[2] = 4;
    test[10] = 0;

    test.print();


    test2.insert(0, 50.0);

}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:

    Vector();
    Vector(T aSize);
    ~Vector();
    int getSize();
    int getPosition(T position);
    void print() const;
    void insert(T position, T value);
    void resize(int newSize);
    int &operator[](int index);


private:
    T size;
    int vLength;
    T* data;
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector() 
{
    Vector::Vector(vLength);
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] data;
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(T aSize)
{
    size = aSize;
    data = new T[size];
    for (T i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::print() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
int Vector<T>::getPosition(T position)
{
    return data[position];
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::insert(T position, T value)
{
    data[position] = value;

    cout << "value: " << value << " was inserted into position: " << position << endl;
}
template <class T>
int Vector<T>::getSize()
{
    cout << "the array size is: " << size << endl;
    return size;
}

template <class T>
int &Vector<T>::Vector::operator[](int index)
{
    if ((index - 1) > size) {
        resize(index + 1);
    }
    return data[index];
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::resize(int newSize)
{
    T *temp;
    temp = new T[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }

    delete[] data;
    data = temp;
    size = newSize;

    cout << "the array was resized to: " << newSize << endl;
}
```

Comment: Future armour: Familiarize yourself with the [Rule of Three and its friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: okay thankyou for that

Comment: In resize, you should go up-to `size` and not `newSize` to reading `data` out of scope. And `getPosition` should be: `T Vector<T>::getPosition(int position)` since you return a value contains in `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the generic type `T` to set the size of the dynamic array. Also you should not use `T` to loop through a container. You should use an integral type instead (`int`, `long`, etc).

Comment: i realised i changed that just to try a new thing aha, i changed it back but still nothing

Comment: okay so i changed the (T aSize) to (int aSize) and that got rid of first error but subscript is not of integral type is still displaying

Comment: Remember that in your class definition, `size` is still of type `T`, and so the statement `size = aSize;` is incorrect.

Comment: @Getwrong Don't use `T` for any of the indexes. `T` is the type of the data. All of the  sizes and indices must be integers. Recommendation write less code between cycles of compiling and testing. You'll find you're less likely to repeat a mistake once you found it once. Lateo, I recommend expanding the answer to cover the other family of errors.

Comment: At first look, I don't see anything wrong, so I will reproduce the code on my computer.

Comment: @Getwrong the downside of changing the question is you've now made the previously correct make no sense. Be careful when changing the question after answers have been made.

Comment: There are now no mistakes in the code. I'm reverting the edit.

Comment: @user4581301, sugar. sorry about that i will re adjust my question

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me. Are you sure you are still getting the desired error?

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon. There is one potential mistake left that I can see. On resize the old data is copied to the new buffer, but the rest of the new buffer is not cleared and will contain uninitialized elements.